# Ubuntu 18.04 buggy in new user after creating new user

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, favorites

I created a new user for hadoop, I am using the computer with the new user, I mean I switched to it. After using in this new user I have lots of bugs:

- I can't change keyboard layout, It was Turkish Q but it changed to US. Settings->Region and language->Adding new input source doesn't work.
  [image: The new input source screen]
- I can't pin anything to the task bar, I can't change the applications positions, I can't unpin.
  [image: favorite programs]
- I can't change desktop background image.
- Ubuntu asks me for upgrade every hour(this seems stopped after playing with Software Updater)
  This seemed a chmod or sudo problem to me. What do you suggest?

I created user by this way:

```
sudo addgroup hadoop
sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser
```

After that, I switched to the new user with "Switch user" option. I tried logging out too.

Comment: How did you create the new user?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I did it from command line, edited the question accordingly

Comment: Switching to it via `su` won't magically make you run a complete session as the new user. You'd better give it a password, log out, and log in as the new user.

Comment: Edited accordingly, I switched to that user and used as the new user.

Comment: Ok. Maybe the problem is that you didn't create the `hduser` group. The safest way to create a new user on a desktop is to do it from Settings, and make it belong to possible other groups afterwards.